# How to concat a pattern in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs

I think the title can't describe the question clearly. But I will try to describe in more detail words.

Here is my Emacs lisp code to set the backup folder:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . "/hom/test/.backups")))
```

But if I want to do this job by generating the backup path in a dynamic way, which generates the path based on the user's path.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
(setq temp-file-folder "/home/test")
(setq backups-save-folder (concat temp-file-folder "/.backups"))
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . backups-save-folder)))
```

But it doesn't work. The final output of above code is:

```
(("" . backups-save-folder))
```

I think what I am trying to get should be:

```
(("" . "/home/test/.backups"))
```

So, what's the right code to generate the path dynamic? What's the meaning of . in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, a point. You can use the `format` function instead of concat to do this (it's similar to `printf`). Here is an example

```
(let ((home_dir "/home/noufal")
      (posts_dir "posts"))
  (format "%s/%s" home_dir posts_dir))
```

evaluates to `"/home/noufal/posts"`

It's not idiomatic lisp to `setq` temporary variables. You should work within the scope of a `let` construct which can bind values to a few temporary symbols and then get your work done.

In your last case, you've used a `'` before your second parameter. This will prevent it from being evaluated (it's synonymous to "quote literally") and so, the `backups-save-folder` will not be replaced with the value. If you want do that, do something like this.

```
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons ""  backups-save-folder)))
```

The `.` is a way of representing lists whose `cdr` is not a list. Refer the [elisp documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html#Dotted-Pair-Notation) for more details.

Comment: You could also use quasiquote, which looks nicer IMO.  (setq backup-directory-alist `(("" . ,backups-save-folder)))

Comment: According to your suggestion, I have added following code and it works:(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons "" 
                                         (let ((backups_dir "/.backups")
                                               (temp_folder desktop-temp-file-folder))
                                           (format "%s/%s" temp_folder backups_dir)))))

Answer (score 0):

seems you don't need an associated list, designed to store paired values, but a simple list:

get the current user directory (getenv "HOME")

maybe combined with another arbitrary string "-BACKSTAGE-AREA"

(setq my-dir (list (concat (getenv "HOME")"-BACKSTAGE-AREA")))

get the directory name stored that way with

(car my-dir)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Noufal Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229602/noufal-ibrahim)'s answer, here is my final code:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons "" 
                                     (let ((backups_dir "/.backups")
                                           (temp_folder desktop-temp-file-folder))
                                       (format "%s/%s" temp_folder backups_dir)))))
```

It works.

Thanks